# Swaption trade data elements

Tags: swaption, trade

Can someone please list all the
Swaption trade data elements.
I am doing research and trying to ensure I document all key data elements of a Swaption trade.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about interest rate swaptions:
Expiration date and time ;
Type of option (payer, receiver, or straddle) ;
Start and end date of underlying swap;
Details of the underlying swap:
Fixed rate and payment dates of the fixed leg ;
Floating rate and payment dates of the floating leg

Comment: I’d also add the settlement behavior; ie cash / physical settlement and maybe even the collateralisation of the underlying swap.

Comment: I agree with @Kermittfrog.  Several settlements are possible: cash settlement , in which case one needs to specify the relevant index; cleared physical settle , in which case one needs to specify the exchange ; and uncleared physical settle, in which case the underlying swap will be an otc swap between the two participants.